# updating ehcache from database update

Tags: caching, ehcache

I would like to know if there's a way for ehcache to detect a database update/insert (spring/java, hibernate web application) and refresh its cache with the current(latest) data from the database if not, what would be the best way detect a database update so as to keep the data between and cache and database in sync?

Answer (score 2):

Caching tools (ehcahce , infinispan) provides the solution other way round, i-e, to refresh the cache with DB data in configured interval , for example : every 15 or 30 minutes. Don't use cache, if the data keeps changing continuously...

Comment: thanks for your reply. I kinda realised this. In ehcache you can use listeners, in theory could I set a listener on a update method which could trigger an update? Still exploring listeners at the moment

Comment: as per my understanding, ehcache event listerers are meant for cache events (eg :- element has been added, removed, or expired) and not for DB events.